# React eCommerce app not able to fetch data from backend, throwing error 400 on the debugger

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, stripe-payments

Creating a React eCommerce app, deployed on Firebase and Payment gateaway is integrated with stripe.

As soon as I place an order, I am supposed to push it to the backend, and again fetch it back to the front end to show the order details to the user.

This is the code in "Index.js" in "Functions" folder, which serves the API call:

```
const express = require('express');
 const cors = require('cors');
const stripe = require("stripe")
("XXXXXXXX");

// API

// - App Config
const app = express();

// - Middlewears
app.use(cors({ origin: true }))
app.use(express.json());

// - API routes
app.get("/", (request, response) => response.status(200).send('hello world'))

app.post("/payments/create", async (request, response) => {
    const total = request.query.total;

    console.log("Payment Request Revieved for this amount ->", total)

    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount: total, // subunits of currency
        currency: "usd",
    });
    // 201 - OK - Created Something
    response.status(201).send({
        clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret
    });
})

// - Listen Command
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

These are the errors I'm getting in the browser debugger

```
It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK.
When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to only import
the individual SDK components you intend to use.

For the module builds, these are available in the following manner
(replace <PACKAGE> with the name of a component - i.e. auth, database, etc):

CommonJS Modules:
const firebase = require('firebase/app');
require('firebase/<PACKAGE>');

ES Modules:
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/<PACKAGE>';

Typescript:
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/<PACKAGE>';

./node_modules/firebase/dist/index.esm.js @ index.ts:18
```

This:

```
v3:1 You may test your Stripe.js integration over HTTP. However, live Stripe.js integrations must use HTTPS.
```

Also this:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
```

And these errors are showing in my VS code terminal:

```
(node:1700) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: This value must be greater than or equal to 1.
>      at Function.generate (D:\WebDev\TutorialProjects\React\AmazonClone\amazon-clone\functions\node_modules\stripe\lib\Error.js:40:16)
>      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (D:\WebDev\TutorialProjects\React\AmazonClone\amazon-clone\functions\node_modules\stripe\lib\StripeResource.js:203:33)
>      at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
>      at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
>      at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
>      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) 
>  (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)  
>  (node:1700) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
>  (node:1700) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're not setting `amount` correctly, but you're suppressing the details of the Stripe API error response, which would make this more obvious. You should add some debug logging in your `/payments/create` handler. Check your [Dashboard logs](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs) to see the full error details another way.

What is the request shape that your client app makes to your back end on that endpoint? You're using `express.json()` as though you expect some json-encoded POST body, but then your handler is looking at query parameters with `request.query.total`. Have you checked whether you're getting the expected value here?

You need to send an `amount` that is both >=1 and at least the [minimum charge](https://stripe.com/docs/currencies#minimum-and-maximum-charge-amounts) for your currency.